# Проблема с потоками...

Tags: .net, c++

Здравствуйте!
Начал только что изучать потоки, возникла проблема. Мне нужно использовать многопоточность в winForms приложениях... Проблема в том, что winForm приложение компилируется в студии с отметкой: Pure MSIL Common Language Runtime Support (/clr:pure), а приложение "с потоками", консольное:

```
// [C++]
// Compile using /clr option.
#using <mscorlib.dll>
 using namespace System;
 using namespace System::Threading;
 // Simple threading scenario:  Start a Shared method running
 // on a second thread.
class ThreadExample 
 {
 public:
     // The ThreadProc method is called when the thread starts.
     // It loops ten times, writing to the console and yielding 
     // the rest of its time slice each time, and then ends.
     static void ThreadProc()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
         {
             Console::Write("ThreadProc: ");
             Console::WriteLine(i);
             // Yield the rest of the time slice.
             Thread::Sleep(0);
         }
     }
 };

 int main() 
 {
     Console::WriteLine("Main thread: Start a second thread.");
     // Create the thread, passing a ThreadStart delegate that
     // represents the ThreadExample::ThreadProc method.  For a 
     // delegate representing a static method, no object is
     // required.
     Thread *oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(0, &ThreadExample::ThreadProc));

     // Start the thread.  On a uniprocessor, the thread does not get 
     // any processor time until the main thread yields.  Uncomment
     // the Thread.Sleep that follows t.Start() to see the difference.
     oThread->Start();
     //Thread::Sleep(0);

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         Console::WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
         Thread::Sleep(0);
     }

     Console::WriteLine("Main thread: Call Join(), to wait until ThreadProc ends.");
     oThread->Join();
     Console::WriteLine("Main thread: ThreadProc.Join has returned.  Press Enter to end program.");
     Console::ReadLine();
     return 0;
 }
```

компилируется с меткой Common Language Runtime Support, Old Syntax (/clr:oldSyntax). Как совместить этот код в одном приложении(оконном). В чем проблема, почему у них разные common language support runtime? Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, мне кажется новое приложение имеет смысл писать сразу правильно, то есть без oldSyntax....

Почитайте тут [чем оно отличается](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k8d11d4s(v=vs.90).aspx), и [как его переключить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094832/converting-from-c-cli-oldsyntax-how-to-and-can-this-be-automated).

Comment: ... а ещё лучше сразу на C#.